# Command sent on Bot stop/locking

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'd like to know if a command is sent from telegram when a bot is stopped/locked and what is. I've read the telegram bot documentation and googled for this problem but I haven't find a solution.

Where could I find?

Comment: Honestly I can't fully understand your question. Could you please rephrase it ?

Comment: I'd like to know if there's a command sent from telegram to the bot when the user stops/blocks the bot, like /start when the bot is started. Because I've a list with all chat_IDs and if my bot is stopped I'd like to delete this chat_ID from my list. I don't know if now is better

Answer (score 1):

Every time you send a request to Telegram servers you receive a response.

---

> The response contains a JSON object, which always has a Boolean field `ok` and may have an optional String field `description` with a human-readable description of the result. If `ok` equals true, the request was successful and the result of the query can be found in the `result` field. In case of an unsuccessful request, `ok` equals false and the error is explained in the `description`. An Integer ‘error_code’ field is also returned, but its contents are subject to change in the future.

From the [official documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests).

---

As example when you make a request to a blocked bot you may receive a response like that.

```
{
  "ok":false,
  "error_code":403,
  "description":"[Error]: Forbidden: can't write to private chat with deleted user"
}
```

So when the field `ok` is false you know something went wrong.

Comment: The question is not about general Telegram's response to requests but about a message a bot receives when the user stops the bot.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `my_chat_member` update. When user is blocking your bot from his chat (it may be a converation or just a private chat), you will receive it with those fields.

```js
{
 chat: {
   id: 1,
   username: "...",
   type: "private",
 },
 from: {...},
 old_chat_member: {status: "member"}, // is your bot status
 new_chat_member: {status: "kicked"}, // is you new bot status
}
```